# How to enable the GPS positioning UI on Nokia Here Maps for Android

Tags: android, here-api, nokiax

Good Day Devs, I'm currently developing an app using Here Maps SDK but I have a problem. Once I run the map, there are no GPS Positioning UI placed on the Map. Should I code it manually or is there something that I will enable to make it appear? Thank you.

Comment: Correct me If i'm wrong , but is it not that Nokia android has been terminated by Microsoft?

Comment: Yup, but i'm using a HERE SDK specifically for Native Android Device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unofrtunately there are no ready made things to get this done, thus You would need to code it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their PositionManager for your app. Represents a manager for information received from positioning devices, such as updates to the current position and the average speed.

Link provided [HERE](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-common-positioningmanager.html)